# JS scope Problem

Tags: javascript, extjs

how to i access "myhandler" from within "title->tbar->item->handler:

```
Application.MenuPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, { 
 title: 'Standard',
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'buttongroup',
        columns: 3,
        title: 'MyTitle',
        items: [{
            text: 'Addl',
            scale: 'large',
            rowspan: 3, iconCls: 'add',
            iconAlign: 'top',
            cls: 'x-btn-as-arrow',
            handler: this.myHandler.createDelegate(this, ['Hello World'])  // <-- How to acces myHandler()?
        },
        {
            text: 'Delete',
            scale: 'large',
            rowspan: 3, iconCls: 'delete',
            iconAlign: 'top',
            cls: 'x-btn-as-arrow'
        },
        ]
    }]


,myHandler : function (name) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Inside', 'Hello ' + name);
}
```

});

**Error:**

> this.myHandler is undefined
>   [Break on this error] handler: this.myHandler.createDelegate(this, ['Hello World'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second argument of extend, you are declaring an object that will be merged into the prototype of your class.

In your statement, *this* is resolved during declaration process, not during instanciation. Therefore, *this* refers to the context where you declared this class, and not to a future instance of it.

You should assign the handler in the constructor. I don't know which name it has in ExtJs but it could be something like initialize:

```
Application.MenuPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, { 
    title: 'Standard',
    tbar: null,
    initialize: function() {
        this.myHandler.createDelegate(this, ['Hello World']);
        this.tbar = [{
            xtype: 'buttongroup',
            columns: 3,
            title: 'MyTitle',
            items: [{
              text: 'Addl',
              scale: 'large',
              rowspan: 3, iconCls: 'add',
              iconAlign: 'top',
              cls: 'x-btn-as-arrow',
              handler: this.myHandler.createDelegate(this, ['Hello World']) 
             },
          {
              text: 'Delete',
              scale: 'large',
              rowspan: 3, iconCls: 'delete',
              iconAlign: 'top',
              cls: 'x-btn-as-arrow'
          },
          ]
          }];

    },


    myHandler : function (name) {
      Ext.Msg.alert('Inside', 'Hello ' + name);
    }
}
```

note: only assign primitives types ( strings, integer ) in the prototype because objects properties won't be cloned, therefore any instances will share the same reference. This is desirable for functions only, generally.

Comment: Thanks. Working example below.

Answer (score 0):

Final and working solution. Thanks BiAiB.

```
Application.MenuPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, { 
    title: 'Standard',
    tbar: null,
    initComponent: function() {

        Ext.apply(this, {

            tbar : [{
                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                columns: 3,
                title: 'MyTitle',
                items: [{
                  text: 'Addl',
                  scale: 'large',
                  rowspan: 3, iconCls: 'add',
                  iconAlign: 'top',
                  cls: 'x-btn-as-arrow',
                  handler: this.myHandler.createDelegate(this, ['Hello World']) 
                 },
              {
                  text: 'Delete',
                  scale: 'large',
                  rowspan: 3, iconCls: 'delete',
                  iconAlign: 'top',
                  cls: 'x-btn-as-arrow'
              },
              ]
              }]
        })
        Application.MenuPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },


    myHandler : function (name) {
      Ext.Msg.alert('Inside', 'Hello ' + name);
    }
});
```